# Problems using auth0 Quick Start Guide for cordova

Tags: cordova, auth0

So after having trouble integrating the auth0 in my cordova app I decided to run the official provided [sample app](https://github.com/auth0-community/auth0-cordova-samples/tree/master/01-Login). But after following the provided instructions I am still not able to make it work.
I get the error that

```
Error in Success callbackId: SafariViewController1859440610 : TypeError: Object.assign is not a function
```

I can't find any similar problem reported on google or know how to track it. Any leads and help would be appreciated.
My plugiins/fetch.json looks like this

```
{
"cordova-plugin-inappbrowser": {
    "source": {
        "type": "registry",
        "id": "cordova-plugin-inappbrowser@~1.3.0"
    },
    "is_top_level": true,
    "variables": {}
},
"cordova-plugin-whitelist": {
    "source": {
        "type": "registry",
        "id": "cordova-plugin-whitelist@~1.2.1"
    },
    "is_top_level": true,
    "variables": {}
},
"cordova-plugin-customurlscheme": {
    "source": {
        "type": "registry",
        "id": "cordova-plugin-customurlscheme@^4.3.0"
    },
    "is_top_level": true,
    "variables": {
        "URL_SCHEME": "com.auth0.cordova.example",
        "ANDROID_SCHEME": "com.auth0.cordova.example",
        "ANDROID_HOST": "tsm-test.eu.auth0.com",
        "ANDROID_PATHPREFIX": "/cordova/com.auth0.cordova.example/callback"
    }
},
"cordova-plugin-safariviewcontroller": {
    "source": {
        "type": "registry",
        "id": "cordova-plugin-safariviewcontroller"
    },
    "is_top_level": true,
    "variables": {}
}
```

}

and my config.xml is:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="com.auth0.cordova.example" version="1.0.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:gap="http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0">
        <name>Auth0 Example</name>
        <description>
            Login sample application that responds to the deviceready event and authenticates using Auth0
        </description>
        <author email="support@auth0.com" href="http://auth0.com">
            Auth0 Team
        </author>
        <content src="index.html" />
        <preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true" />
        <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="16" />
        <platform name="android">
        </platform>
        <platform name="ios">
        </platform>
        <access origin="*" />
        <platform name="android">
            <allow-intent href="market:*" />
        </platform>
        <platform name="ios">
            <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
            <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
        </platform>
        <preference name="AndroidLaunchMode" value="singleTask" />
        <engine name="android" spec="^6.2.3" />
        <engine name="ios" spec="~4.4.0" />
        <plugin name="cordova-plugin-inappbrowser" spec="~1.7.1" />
        <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="~1.3.2" />
        <plugin name="cordova-plugin-customurlscheme" spec="^4.3.0">
            <variable name="URL_SCHEME" value="com.auth0.cordova.example" />
            <variable name="ANDROID_SCHEME" value="com.auth0.cordova.example" />
            <variable name="ANDROID_HOST" value="tsm-test.eu.auth0.com" />
            <variable name="ANDROID_PATHPREFIX" value="/cordova/com.auth0.cordova.example/callback" />
        </plugin>
        <plugin name="cordova-plugin-safariviewcontroller" spec="^1.4.7" />
    </widget>
```

The Domain in the Clients side is `tsm-test.eu.auth0.com`

The Allowed Callback URLs is set as [image]
and Allowed Origins (CORS) is `file://*`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was facing similar error while implementing Auth0 in android, and as mentioned in this 
link https://github.com/pburtchaell/react-notification/issues/65, I added 'babel-polyfill' to the entry point in my "webpack.config.js" file.

```
entry: ['babel-polyfill','./src/index.js'],
```

Now the Auth0 works fine in my android app.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you may not have installed the necessary Cordova plugins. Taken from the [readme with the quickstart sample](https://github.com/auth0-community/auth0-cordova-samples/tree/master/01-Login#install-cordova-plugins):

### Install Cordova Plugins

Several Cordova plugins are required for use with `@auth0/cordova`. Install `safariviewcontroller` and `customurlscheme` with the following commands.

> cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-safariviewcontroller
>
> cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-customurlscheme --variable
>   URL_SCHEME={YOUR_PACKAGE_ID} --variable
>   ANDROID_SCHEME={YOUR_PACKAGE_ID} --variable
>   ANDROID_HOST={YOUR_AUTH0_DOMAIN} --variable
>   ANDROID_PATHPREFIX=/cordova/{YOUR_PACKAGE_ID}/callback

The variables used when installing `cordova-plugin-customurlscheme` are the same as those used to set up the **Callback URL** in your Auth0 Dashboard.

In other words, just run those two commands above in your favourite commant prompt / terminal. That second instruction looks a bit overwhelming - but if you are using the default package id (that comes with the quickstart) - then just use:

> cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-customurlscheme --variable
>   URL_SCHEME=com.auth0.cordova.example --variable
>   ANDROID_SCHEME=com.auth0.cordova.example --variable
>   ANDROID_HOST={YOUR_TENANT}.auth0.com --variable
>   ANDROID_PATHPREFIX=/cordova/com.auth0.cordova.example/callback

and replace {YOUR_TENANT} with your own Auth0 Tenant.

By the way, the allowed callback URL in your Auth0 dashboard should also look like this (again, assuming you are using the default package identifier):

> com.auth0.cordova.example://{YOUR_TENANT}.auth0.com/cordova/com.auth0.cordova.example/callback

Of course, let me know if this does not solve your issue by leaving comments below. Good luck.

Comment: Hi @arcseldon thanks for the reply. i have installed both the plugins as per instructions. I will edit the question to include my show config.xml has required parameters. 
I also do not know what safariviewcontroller plugin has to do with android. So i removed that plugin built again and tried to run on my android phone but that doesn't work either.

Comment: Try using iOS simulator just to see whether it works. Are you on a Mac? I tested this today from a fresh download and it worked first time...  sorry, if that sounds unhelpful but just reassuring you the sample works. But.. i tried against iOS simulator.

Comment: Perhaps also try uninstalling the app from your simulator / device, nuking your ios / android platforms, removing node_modules and reinstalling, building and generating the platforms again.  Know this sounds like a pretty poor suggestion but once in a while it does actually work.

Comment: I am using linux in a VM. Tried using a different PC and windows. It didn't work.

Comment: But I built the same package on a Mac and ran the app on iPhone and its working.